# client-server websocket communication

Tags: java, javascript, websocket, client-server

I'm building a simple web app with front-end written in html/JavaScript and back end in java. I wanted to know, if I have two buttons, and pressing each button will execute a different function on the server end. What data should I pass to the server using web sockets to execute the respective function in the server end ? I cant directly call a java function from the javascript event handler code. I was thinking of sending button id of the button clicked but is there a better solution?

Comment: you could just use AJAX, instead of web sockets.  Your question is too broad.  How do I know what data you need to pass? Especially since I don't even know the goal of your application.

Comment: I need websockets because I want to send message from server to client without client request. I want to execute a server side function in java depending on the button clicked on frontend

Comment: Your question says, "what should I send to the server".  The rest of my comment stands how would someone now what data you need to send to the server?  Do you mean how do you make the connection to send the data?

Comment: I know how to make the connection. Just what data regarding the button pressed should  I send to the server, so once the server receives the message it will call the java function based on the data it receives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by sending button ID.